# olympiad problem using the fact that $|G|\leq f(|\mathrm{Aut}(G)|)$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, automorphism-group

I've recently become aware of this result:

**Theorem 1.** There exists a strictly increasing function $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$, such that for any finite group $G$, the following inequality holds: $$|G|\leq f(|\mathrm{Aut}(G)|)$$

I was wondering if by any chance there would exists a math olympiad problem that could be tackled using **Theorem 1**? That would be nice!

If not, maybe it is possible to create one? I'm not too familiar with the method to create problems, so if someone could help me, I'll appreciate it! (or even giving me an hint on how to start).

N.B : the proof of **Theorem 1** actually gives such a $f$. If $h:n\mapsto \max \varphi^{-1}(\{2,\dots, n\})$ (with $\varphi$ the Euler totient function), then $f(n) = h(n)\cdot n^{2n^3+2}$ works.

Comment: So, you're looking for a *problem*, not a solution? I think that's off-topic.

Comment: @Shaun If one exists already, the question is like a reference request. And if it doesn't, then it's like asking for applications of a certain flavor. I think the question might be okay on those grounds.

Comment: It is precisely what Mark S said. Maybe I should add a tag for "reference request"

Comment: The "nearly" is useless, I'll remove it. If $G$ is abelian, then $f=h$ works. Else, $f:n\mapsto h(n)\cdot n^{2n^3}$ works. $h$ comes from the fact that $\varphi(|\mathrm{Aut}(G)|) \leq |G|$ (with $\varphi$ the Euler's totient function).

Comment: You could take $f(n) = (n-1)!$, a very crude bound that works since each automorphism $f$ is a bijection that fixes the identity element of $G$. It is more difficult and more interesting to prove that there exists an increasing function $f$ such that $f(|G|) \leq |Aut(G)|$ for all finite groups $G$. Anyway, I don't have an answer to your question, and it is a bit too vague.

Comment: How does $f(n) = (n-1)!$ works? I may be wrong, but what you gave me was a $f$ such that $|\mathrm{Aut}(G)|\leq f(|G|)$ isn't it? The question is the other way around, to find an $f$ such that $|G|\leq f(|\mathrm{Aut}(G)|)$

Comment: @KeryannMassin: Oh I see, you are right - I think I misread the inequality. It reminded me of the old result which shows that $|Aut(G)| \rightarrow \infty$ as $|G| \rightarrow \infty$.